# Need to extract characters from a sentence in php

Tags: php, regex

I am having a sentence like

":    Lim Chee Kong \ S717613 IB    CUST."

I need to extract the name Lim Chee Kong. That is the first word before or after any numbers or special chars using php preg match or any other rule.

The sentence can be dynamic.

Comment: Do all sentence have Lim Chee Kong or name is also dynamic?

Comment: How is Lim Chee Kong echo'ed? Out of an array?

Comment: The name also dynamic. It is extracted from an array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$str = ": Lim Chee Kong \ S717613 IB CUST.";
$res = preg_split("/[^A-Za-z]/",$str);
$result = Array();
$wordFound = false;
$noMoreWords = false;
foreach($res as $key=>$words) {
    if($words != '' && !$noMoreWords) {
        $result[] = $words;
        $wordFound = true;
    }
    if($wordFound && $words == '') {
        $noMoreWords = true;
    }
}
echo implode(" ",$result); //Lim Chee Kong
```

Comment: Why you don't use a preg_match (13 lines vs 1line of code)? (-;

Answer (score 0):

Your definition of the regex is not compatible with you example.
"That is the first word..." -> Lim Chee Kong is not a word. It is a group of words, seperated by blanks
"...before or after any number of special chars" -> This is also true for the substring "IB CUST" in your example.

That said, the following is matching a group of words optionally surrounded by special chars:

```
\W*\b([a-zA-Z\s]+)\b\W*
```

In your example, this gets "Lim Chee Kong" and "IB CUST".

Answer (score 0):

As you noted the name is echo'ed out of an array you could do this: *(I don't see why you want to split it).*

**Your Array** as an example:

```
$array = ['name' => 'Lim Chee Kong', 'extra' => 'S717613 IB CUST'];
```

**Echo it:**

```
echo ' ":' . $array['name'] . ' \ ' . $array['extra'] . '." ';
```

**Outcome:**

> ": Lim Chee Kong \ S717613 IB CUST."

The array could contain other information to be echo'ed. Is this what you need?

Comment: I need the outcome as Lim Chee Kong and  ": Lim Chee Kong \ S717613 IB CUST." this is a sentence.

Comment: Ok. Sorry, did not understood what 'sentence' ment. But I googled it, now I understand lol.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the [preg_match](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) function for that.

Example:

```
<?php
$string = ": Lim Chee Kong \ S717613 IB CUST.";
preg_match('/^[^\w]*([\w\s]+)\s[^\w]+/', $string, $m);
echo $m[1];
```